# LUIS.ai Is adding spaces around dashes and underscores in returned entities

Tags: botframework, azure-language-understanding

I'm using MS Bot Framework, C#, with LUIS.ai. I've found that LUIS.ai adds a space both before and after dashes or underscores in the entities it finds in an utterance.

For example if the user types:

"search for transition-document files in my project"

and "transition-document files" is determined to be an entity the actual LUIS entity object changes it to be "transition - document files"

Other than simply replacing all " - " and " _ " with "-" and "_" respectively, can I just stop LUIS from doing this?

Answer (score 4):

> LUIS.ai adds a space both before and after dashes or underscores in the entities it finds in an utterance.

As you said, the whitespaces will be added when an utterance contains some special characters. For example, when I do with something like URL that contains `/` and `.` etc, same issue appears.

And as I know, currently LUIS seems not enable us to stop this by doing some configuration or settings. To solve this problem, you can try to handle that in your code to remove whitespace from matched entities `"transition - document"` by using regular expression.

Comment: Thanks for your response, Fei. Do you happen to have any insight into why LUIS does this?

Comment: `why LUIS does this?` I suspect that it could help LUIS [tokenizes utterances](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/master/articles/cognitive-services/LUIS/luis-supported-languages.md#tokenization)

Answer (score 1):

You can override this on a LuisDialog and replace any entities where you need the exact text:

```
    protected override Task DispatchToIntentHandler(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> item, IntentRecommendation bestIntent, LuisResult result)
    {
        // remove spaces LUIS adds before and after dashes and underscores
        EntityRecommendation resourceNameEntity = result.Entities.Where(e => e.Type == Luis_EntityTypes.ResourceName).FirstOrDefault();
        if (resourceNameEntity != null)
        {
            resourceNameEntity.Entity = resourceNameEntity.Entity.Replace(" - ", "-").Replace(" _ ", "_");
        }

        return base.DispatchToIntentHandler(context, item, bestIntent, result);
    }
```